# I need some advice about DOCX format sync(iOS) for using google drive api. Anyone can help me?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-drive-api, opendocument

Using DOCX to make sync, Insert, Download, Update works find but JPEG image header disappears. Questions is that is it forced to get rid of on the server while converting JPEC header? 
I’m using mimeType as "application/msword".

Comment: Sorry, is it a Drive or Drive SDK question. I think even if you upload the same file on drive.google.com, it's missing the header. Am I right?

Comment: yes. I have uploaded the same jpeg file in .docx document on drive.google.com directly.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Google Drive product questions on the [Google Drive product forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive).